# How to return duplicates within a table that share the same value within another column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I return the ProductNumbers where the Number is duplicated when it has the same year ?
This is all within the same table.
in this example below, I would expect ProductNumber 123 and 456 to be returned.
Explain reasoning if possible, thank you!

```
ProductNumber   Numb     Year
123             45        1
456             45        1
789             45        2
109             54        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select * 
from yourtable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable t2
    where t.productnumber != t2.productnumber 
          and t.numb = t2.numb
          and t.year = t2.year
    )
```

Using `exists`, we check to see if there are other records in the same table whose `productnumber` is different, but have the same `numb` and `year` values.

Comment: Thank you sgeddes, unfortunately the table isn't indexed so I lose connection when I try this query. :(

Comment: @onion This is probably the most efficient way to get your results.  Not sure what you mean when you say you lose connection. If this is timing out and your table has a lot of data, then you could benefit from an `index` on `productnumber, numb, year`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table T1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM 
        (SELECT Numb ,Year 
        FROM Table
        GROUP BY Numb
                ,Year 
        HAVING COUNT(1)>1
        ) T2
    WHERE T1.Numb = T2.Tumb
      AND T1.Year = T2.Year
)
```

Comment: Thank you zeki, unfortunately the table isn't indexed so I lose connection when I try this query. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT t1.ProductNumber
FROM Products t1
INNER JOIN Products as t2
ON t1.ProductNumber != t2.ProductNumber
          AND t1.Numb = t2.Numb
          AND t1.Year = t2.Year
```